# synology nas DS213 J rsync files from ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, synology, keys

I´ve a Synology DS213 J Nas System. I´m trying to sync folders from a ubuntu 12.04 webserver to the nas without password prompt.
therefore I logged into the nas via terminal with root account.

Created the ssh dir /root/.ssh

```
$ mkdir /root/.ssh
```

created the keys with

```
   $ ssh-keygen
```

-> with empty paraphrase

Thus ssh-copy-id is not working on the synology nas i copied the id_rsa.pub
by hand to the ubuntu machine

```
$ cat id_rsa.pub
```

Copy and paste it on ubuntu Server to

```
$ ~/.ssh/nas.pub
```

and "cated" the file into authorized_keys

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/nas.pub >> authorized_keys
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config is set to

```
has RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Unfortunately If I´m trying an rsync I´m asked for the empty paraphrase and the password for the ubuntu machine.
helpful for any hint,

toni

Comment: Thanks, your tipp with the correct directory did it, the key resisted in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mixed up usernames and authorized keys.

1. Does 'cat ~/.ssh/nas.pub >> authorized_keys' actually put your key into '~/.ssh/authorized_keys' where it should be, and NOT into '~/authorized_keys'?
2. have you tried to ssh (not rsync) to the webserver from your NAS?
   Which username do you use to run rsync/ssh from rsync? Did you put
   your key into .ssh/authorized_keys for THAT username?

DETAILS:

You should have a user that runs rsync command on NAS. Let's call him 'userNAS'. The 'ssh-keygen' should be run by this user. Then you need a public key of this user, /home/userNAS/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.

This step probably worked fine for you, I assume you used root user for it. However, it's not clear from your question how have you executed '$ mkdir /root/.ssh', as '$' shows that you are not root.

Next, you need to be able to login via ssh on the Webserver. For this, you should have another user on the webserver, let's call him 'userWeb'. Now you need to copy the public key of 'userNAS' from your NAS to the 'authorized_keys' of user 'userWeb' on your webserver. E.g., to '/home/userWeb/.ssh/authorized_keys'.

Now you should be able to run 'ssh userWeb@yourwebserver.com' as 'userNAS' on your NAS and login to webserver as user 'userWeb'. However, if your user on the webserver is also root, ssh will not allow it to log in. Check the separate option in ssh configuration to enable root logins via ssh. However, this is not recommended.

Finally, rsync should have an option telling it, that it should login as 'userWeb' on the webserver. Something like '-e ssh userWeb@yourwebserver.com:/remote/dir'